# What is an alternative for "Considering the fact that"

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

What is an alternative expression for "Considering the fact that"?

To understand the context, please consider the following sentence:

"Considering the fact that mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and industries."

Comment: "Considering that mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and industries." You don't need "the fact". OR "Given that mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and industries."

Comment: Simply "considering", or "given that", or "understanding that", or "with the knowledge that", or "knowing that".

Comment: "Because" is the word if you think about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative is to omit *the fact" and use *considering that*:

> "*Considering that* mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems
>   appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and
>   industries."

Another alternative is *given that*:

> "*Given that* mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems
>   appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and
>   industries."

Yet another alternative is *in that*:

> "*In that* mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems
>   appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and
>   industries."

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the single word *Since* to replace *Considering the fact that:*

> Since mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and industries.

Comment: My first thought was "_as_" and was about to add an answer when I saw this. (Also, _because_ should work). +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with *taking into account*.

> Taking into account that mixed-use buildings were new at the time, it seems appropriate that the builders came from different backgrounds and industries.